# Countdown Using While Loop with Mystery Number

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have seen various ways to countdown, but I have a mystery number I want to count down from by 3's and I want it to "print "0" if I lands on it". Also, it has to be a for while loop.

This is the closest I have got, but it doesn't print 0 (when my mystery number changes) as 0 is the end of the range. If I change the range to say -1 then the autocorrect says I am not using a For While loop.

*myst_int provided

```
i in range(mystery_int,0,-3):
    print(i)
```

When I try to set it up with "While" I end up creating an infinite loop and it breaks.
example: `while mystery >= 0:`

Answer (score 0):

This should work. In python, choosing carefully how the loop runs can be crucial.

```
import random

mystery_int = random.randint(10,100)
print(mystery_int)

while mystery_int >= 3:
    mystery_int -= 3
    print(mystery_int)
```